# Pythagorean Proof!

Tags: geometry

Point P is inside rectangle ABCD. Show that PA^2 + PC^2 = PB^2 + PD^2.

I am having trouble proving that it works for ANY point inside the rectangle.

Problem Hints:
Squares of lengths suggest the Pythagorean Theorem.

Please help!

Comment: Maybe Ptolemy's Theorem could work.

Answer (score 3):

Brute force:
$$PA^2+PC^2=(PE^2+PF^2)+(PG^2+PH^2)=$$
$$ (PE^2+PH^2)+(PF^2+PG^2)=PD^2+PB^2$$

[image]

Comment: Can you explain how you know PA^2 + PC^2 = (PE^2 + PF^2) + (PG^2 + PH^2)?

Comment: @Clancy - note that $PE=FA$, and $PF=AE$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Draw parallel lines with the sides of the rectangle through $P$, name the segments, and indeed, use the Pythagorean theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a geometric approach. Notice that $PA^2$ is the sum of the two red sqaures, $PB^2$ is the sum of the two blue squares, etc. The numbers on the squares represent squares of equal areas.

$PA^2+PC^2=PB^2+PD^2=1+2+3+4$

[image]